# Cardiovascular complications associated with COVID 19 by vaccination status and, if vaccinated, by type

Tags: covid-19, cardiovascular-disease, complications

I apologize if this is an obvious question.  I think I am not finding research on this because I am asking the question wrong in literature searches.  I am far outside my normal area of academic research.

What I am trying to determine is the incidence of various types of cardiovascular complications, such as arrhythmias, by vaccine status (vaccinated/unvaccinated) and if vaccinated, by type of vaccine if known.  I have found overall incidences for various complications including by hospitalization status such as admitted, in ICU, and so forth.

Also, as I am not a physician, virologist, biologist or so on, is there another question that I should be asking that I am not asking.  For example, should I be also looking at things such as a delayed onset?  I am trying to get a policy picture of the impact of various pharmaceutical interventions on CV outcomes.

**EDIT**
Just to be clear what I am asking, I am posting this edit.  If we had a very large sample where some were vaccinated and some were unvaccinated and all had tested positive for COVID-19, what percentage would experience tachycardia, heart failure, coronary artery blockage, and so forth from both groups?  What I am asking is if and how much effect vaccination status has in preventing systemic damage, with CV complications acting as a proxy for that.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Does the data and linked information in [this question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/29401/where-is-the-data-for-covid-19-vaccine-safety-in-medium-term-and-or-for-people-w) answer your question?

Comment: @bob1 No, but I will edit the question to be clearer.  I am not interested in vaccine safety but instead outcomes if infected with respect to CV comlications.

Comment: In that case you could use a lot of different measures for systemic damage - how about hospital admissions? Check [this paper out](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/70/wr/mm7043e1.htm)

Comment: Although I'm sure the data is being collected, I doubt any answers have been published at this point. Just too early. I would guess your question will have answers in a few months.

Comment: @bob1 thanks. I will read it.